# Merging two cells into one with a concatinating function in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, merge, concatenation

I need to remove my Z column, but i still need the cell content within it, so i need to transfer that content to the U-column without removing the existing value in the U-column. I'm thinking of doing this function in a help column then copy-paste it over to the U-column I also need to add a text-string that says the following:

"Low voltage US part numbers" followed by the value in Z

Currently i've written the following code:

```
IF(U2>0;CONCAT(U2;CHAR(10);CHAR(10);"Low Voltage US Part numbers: ";Z2);" ")
```

Unfortunately it's not keeping all of the data...

Duly note that Column U and Z does not have values for every row and the code needs to take this into account.

This is how i think the code should be.

If only U2 has text/value (Z2 is empty), it is to keep the value in U2 only (no need for the "Low voltage US part numbers")

If U2 and Z2 have text, these are to be merged (needs to include the concat function so the "Low voltage US part numbers" followed by the Z2 cell-value is included) Also two linebreaks are required, basically the Value in U needs to be two linebreaks above the value in Z.

If only Z2 has text/value, it is to keep the value and the concat function needs to be added. However no linebreak is needed here. Just: Low voltage US part numbers: blah blah blah...

If neither Z2 or U2 has text/value, the cell is to be kept empty

I know the explanation might seem messy, but i would highly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if below formula helps you

`=IF(U2<>"",U2&IF(Z2<>"",CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Low Voltage US Part numbers: "&Z2,""),IF(Z2<>"","Low Voltage US Part numbers: "&Z2,""))`

**Note:** Replace comma with semi-colon!

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for the fast feedback,
Overall, your code looks good, however, I do see some small issues.

One of those being that if U2 and Z2 are empty, the code still writes out the "Low voltage US part numbers". I need to keep the cell empty. (Edit, this was not the case, only happend to one cell "out of many" so no need to do this one...)

Another issue being that i need 2 linebreaks, your code currently have 1. Maybe just add another Char(10)?

I would really appreciate if you could maybe fix this :)

Comment: Hello again,
Mybad...

Your code works without any issues, well done mate.
The only thing i would want is two have two linebreaks. Then the code would meet all of the requested features

Comment: @SwE3xHD See the edited formula. If this answer has helped you then please mark it as answer.